# Do I take two prize cards when a Pokemon-EX is discarded?

Tags: pokemon

When using the Cursed Shovel trainer card and you remove two cards from your opponent’s deck, if one of the discarded cards is a Mega Mewtwo EX, does it entitle me to take two prize cards?

Comment: I've put what seems to be a more appropriate tag on this. If you actually meant to refer to some house rules you are using, please state exactly what those house rules are.

Answer (score 5):

The wording on Cursed Shovel says

> If the Pokémon this card is attached to is Knocked Out by damage from
> an opponent’s attack, discard the top 2 cards of your opponent’s deck

Looking at [The rules here](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2-en-uk/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/swsh3_rulebook_en.pdf) for Pokémon-EX say

> When one of your Pokémon-EX is Knocked Out, your opponent takes 2 Prize cards.

The appendix for 'knocked out' says

> A Pokémon is Knocked Out if it has damage greater than or equal to its
> Hit Points. That Pokémon goes to the discard pile along with all cards
> attached to it. When one of your opponent’s Pokémon is Knocked Out,
> take one of your Prize card

So you would not be entitled to take two prize cards.  You only take a prize card when you knock a Pokemon out.  Cursed shovel places Pokemon in the discard pile, it is not the same as 'knocking out' and would not give a prize at all.